# SQL function, substract variable on another table when insert data

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-function

I have a relational database:

Examination (**ExaminationID**, DetectedDisease, Name)

Uses (**ReagentID**, **ExaminationID**, ReagentQuantity)

Reagent (**ReagentID**, Name, Stock, MinimumPermissibleStock)

Examined (**InsuranceNumber**, ExaminationID, ExaminationDate, Results, TakenResults?)

I want to create a function that when a new record of "examined" is added the quantity of the reagent that examination uses to be substracted from "reagent.stock". Also when reagent.minimumPermissibleStock is lower than stock to return a warning message.

For the second part of the problem i tried this, but it does not work:

```
create function warning() returns trigger AS $warning$
    begin
       if reagent.new.stock < reagent.minimumPermissibleStock then
        raise exception 'Probably mistake';
       end if;
    return new;
    end;
$warning$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT

I tried that one but still it doesnt work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION log_examination2() RETURNS trigger AS $$

DECLARE
    examID integer;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO examination (detecteddisease, ename) VALUES('disease1', 'name') RETURNING examinationID INTO examID;
    INSERT INTO Uses VALUES(reagentID, examID, reagentQuantity);
    UPDATE Reagent SET Stock = Stock - reagentQuantity WHERE ReagentID = reagentID;

    RETURN new;
  END;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;


CREATE TRIGGER validate_quantity AFTER UPDATE OF Stock ON Reagent EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_examination2();
```

Comment: For future reference, please include the version of Postgres you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Triggers can only operate on the table/view to which they are attached--hence the error (I'm assuming you created the trigger as an AFTER UPDATE on Examined).

To actually solve the problem, what you want to do is create a transaction to represent the entire set of operations, and then attach the above function as a trigger AFTER UPDATE to Reagent.

For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION log_examination(int reagentID, int reagentQuantity) AS $$
BEGIN
  BEGIN;
    examID := INSERT INTO Examination VALUE("disease1", "name") RETURNING ExaminationID;
    INSERT INTO Uses VALUE(reagentID, examID, reagentQuantity);
    UPDATE Reagent SET Stock = Stock - reagentQuantity WHERE ReagentID = reagentID;
  COMMIT;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and

```
CREATE TRIGGER validate_quantity AFTER UPDATE OF Stock ON Reagent EXECUTE PROCEDURE warning();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i will try it out as soon as i am back to my workplace!!